# Why Exynos Octa 5420 is unusually slow

Tags: android, c++, performance, android-ndk, arm

My code:

```
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
    struct timespec t,mt1,mt2;
    unsigned long long int mt;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,&mt1);

    //Measured block begin
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,&t);
    //Measured block end

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,&mt2);
    mt = (mt2.tv_sec - mt1.tv_sec)*1000000000LL + mt2.tv_nsec - mt1.tv_nsec;

    printf("%lld\n",mt);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a standalone arm-v7a toolchain generated from Android NDK r9d that resides under `/opt/android-toolchain`.

**Configuration 1:**

These are the default flags generated by the toolchain file in https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake.

Compiler configuration:

```
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ \
    -DANDROID -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-toolchain/sysroot \
    -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char \
    -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp \
    -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections \
    -Wa,--noexecstack  -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer \
    -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/include/c++/4.8 \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/include/c++/4.8/arm-linux-androideabi/armv7-a \
    -o my-object-file.o -c my-source-file.cpp
```

Linker configuration:

```
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    -Wno-psabi --sysroot=/opt/android-toolchain/sysroot \
    -fpic -funwind-tables -finline-limit=64 -fsigned-char \
    -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp \
    -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections \
    -Wa,--noexecstack  -mthumb -fomit-frame-pointer \
    -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 \
    -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections \
    -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now \
    -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc my-object-file.o -o my-executable \
    -L/libs/armeabi-v7a -rdynamic \
    "/opt/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libstdc++.a" \
    "/opt/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libsupc++.a" \
    -lm
```

1. Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Edition with **Exynos Octa 5420 @1.9 Ghz** running Samsung stock 4.4.2 ROM, code takes **2.0 seconds**
2. Samsung Galaxy Note II with **Exynos 4412 @1.6 GHz** running CyanogenMod 11 based on Android 4.4.4, code takes **0.75 seconds**
3. Samsung Galaxy S3 with **Exynos 4412 @1.4 Ghz** running CyanogenMod 11 based on Android 4.4.4, code takes **1.1 seconds**

**Configuration 2:**

Nearly all flags from before are removed.

Compiler configuration:

```
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ \
    -DANDROID --sysroot=/opt/android-toolchain/sysroot \
    -O3 -DNDEBUG \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/include/c++/4.8 \
    -isystem /opt/android-toolchain/include/c++/4.8/arm-linux-androideabi/armv7-a \
    -o my-object-file.o -c my-source-file.cpp
```

Linker configuration:

```
/opt/android-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --sysroot=/opt/android-toolchain/sysroot -O3 -DNDEBUG \
    -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc my-object-file.o -o my-executable \
    -L/libs/armeabi-v7a -rdynamic \
    "/opt/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libstdc++.a" \
    "/opt/android-toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb/libsupc++.a" \
    -lm
```

1. Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Edition with **Exynos Octa 5420 @1.9 Ghz** running Samsung stock 4.4.2 ROM, code takes **2.2 seconds**
2. Samsung Galaxy Note II with **Exynos 4412 @1.6 GHz** running CyanogenMod 11 based on Android 4.4.4, code takes **0.94 seconds**
3. Samsung Galaxy S3 with **Exynos 4412 @1.4 Ghz** running CyanogenMod 11 based on Android 4.4.4, code takes **1.1 seconds**

**Notes for both configurations:**

- I set the the lowest CPU clock frequency to the highest possible, i.e 1.9 Ghz, by a CPU tuning app.
- I made sure there are no background processes hogging the CPU.
- I also tried specifically `-mcpu=cortex-a15` flag, doesn't change the execution time significantly.
- Also tried `-mfpu=neon -marm -mtune=cortex-a15`, doesn't change the execution time significantly.
- `clock_gettime()` is not the culprit, the code is visibly slower.
- Other pieces of code I tried, including parts of OpenCV `imgproc` and STL calls such as `std::map::find()` and `std::sort()` are all **visibly and `clock_gettime()`-measurably slower** on the Exynos Octa 5420 compared to the two others I listed above.

**My hypotheses:**

1. My thread is somehow getting stuck on one of the Cortex-A7 cores instead of hopping on to one of the Cortex-A15 ones. If this might be the case, what can I do to make sure this is the case or how can I force my threads onto the Cortex-A15 cores?
2. I failed to set the CPU clock frequency lower limit and the CPU is being throttled. If this might be the case, how can I make sure that this is the case?
3. Samsung's kernel is somehow worse compared to CM's. Can this cause this much difference in execution time?

I'm pretty much stumped at this point. What are your advices and insights so that I can get my money's worth out of this device?

**Edit:** I flashed a custom tweaked kernel (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2725193) and set the governor to `performance` and execution time went down to about **1.3 seconds**, so I think my 3rd hypothesis is a bit stronger now. It is still slower than the older CPUs though...

Comment: Note that you're essentially benchmarking nothing but the latency of a single system call - the kernel version and configuration are highly likely to be more important than the hardware there. In fact I'm a little surprised that compilation options for this code make any visible difference at all. As for core affinity, [here's a ready-made answer](http://superuser.com/questions/262175/pinning-process-to-a-cpu/262176#262176).

Comment: @Notlikethat, if it was only slow on a system call like `clock_gettime()` I would be more suspicious and less worried; but it's slower on each and every single piece of code I ran. I didn't thoroughly measure how much slower though.

Comment: It is probably first guest. You can try setting affinity to big cores if you can keep all 8 cores online (would probably cause power and heat issues) or use sysfs->..->cpu->..->online mask to only keep big cores online.

Comment: Ah, that was kind of hidden in the question, sorry. Come to think of it, I recall an Exynos 5410 (Odroid-XU) taking considerably longer to run hackbench on 4xA15, compared to a lower-clocked Versatile Express TC2 on 2xA15 + 3xA7. I didn't manage to get a mainline kernel booting on the Odroid for a fair comparison, but I do remember the Exynos defconfig had an awful lot more in it.

Comment: @Notlikethat, thanks for the heads up! This is not good news indeed, where would you suggest that I start looking in order to build my own proper kernel for an Exynos 5?